# Is there a way to sync data in Zoho analytics with Zoho Books using the Zoho API?

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

We've got invoice data in Zoho analytics in a standard table, with invoice numbers, customer numbers, amounts etc, but ideally we want this data in zoho books. Is there a way to use the zoho API to copy this invoice data across into books?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

using API you can create records in zoho books. you can used either flows or deluge API

Comment: Is there a specific way to approach this please?

Comment: there is case: if you want to push data from analytics to zoho books or you want to push from ur other app to zoho books?
-using deluge you can create invoice & then zoho books can be connected with zoho analytics,

Answer (score 0):

"We've got invoice data in Zoho analytics in a standard table, with invoice numbers, customer numbers, amounts etc, but ideally we want this data in zoho books. Is there a way to use the zoho API to copy this invoice data across into books?"-- Better raise/import the invoices in Zoho Books directly. There is import option available for Zoho Books. Zoho Books and Zoho Analytics have in-built one way integration[Zoho Books to Zoho Analytics](so need of coding or separate api call).

It also does auto sync. However to do the setup you need to have admin access for both Zoho Books and Zoho Analytics.